# Services limits for accounts in AWS organization

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

When you create accounts in AWS organization, does each account have their own services limitation?

e.g. Lambda has 1000 concurrency limit for each account. If I created 2 accounts from AWS organization, will I have 1000 concurrent executions / account? (2000 concurrency in total, I know it won't simply sum up to 2000 so this is an oversimplification)

I'm pretty sure this is the case, but I couldn't find any written statement for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service limits are just like any standalone account. No change nor any consolidation in the number of resources provided for a given service.

Only the billing is consolidated for the master account of the AWS Organizations.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this in the following document:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html

If you want to increase the limit there are two possible approaches:

1. Account Level
2. Function Level

More details are given here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html

Thanks,

Comment: yes, I'm aware of the limits for the services. I'm just wondering about is the account created in AWS organization has its own limits (just like a standalone account) or is it consolidated with all other accounts in the organization?